# How large can you make a code such that no subcode is a single parity check code?

Tags: combinatorics, coding-theory

Consider a binary $(k,k,1)$ code $\mathcal C_0$, i.e. $\mathcal C_0 = \mathbb F_2^k$. We extend this to a $(k+1,k,d_1)$ code $\mathcal C_1 = \mathcal C_0 \cup \boldsymbol c_{k+1}$ by appending a column $\boldsymbol c_{k+1} \in \mathbb F_2^{2^k \times 1}$ to the $2^k \times k$ codebook matrix where the rows are codewords. Continuing with the appendation, with $\mathcal C_i = \mathcal C_{i-1} \cup \boldsymbol c_{k+i}$ being a $(k+i,k,d_i)$ code (note that $\mathcal C\cup \boldsymbol c$ is clearly abusing notation - it means "appending the column $\boldsymbol c$ to the codebook matrix representation of the code $\mathcal C$ in this context).

Suppose each $\boldsymbol c_i$ is constrained to have Hamming weight $2^{k-1}$ (i.e. half ones, half zeros) and furthermore must be chosen such that $\boldsymbol c_i \neq \boldsymbol c_j$ and $\boldsymbol x_i \neq \boldsymbol x_j$ where $\boldsymbol x_i$ is a row in the codebook matrix. Then, how many columns can one add before we are certain that $\mathcal C_i$ contains a subcode that is the single-parity check code? Note that any $(k+1,k,2)$ subcode is a single-parity check code.

I'll try to find a solution tomorrow if no one beats me to it. My guess is that the largest value of $k+i$ will have some relation to the sphere-packing bound but I have not formalized that thought yet.

EDIT: Actually, there is one condition missing, namely that the new column $\boldsymbol c_{k+i}$ can not be chosen such that two codewords in $\mathcal C_i$ (i.e. two rows in the codebook matrix) are equal. I've now added it.

For linear codes, it is believable that you can make a $(2^k-2,k)$ code such that no subcode is the SPC because a generator column of Hamming weight $k$ generates a SPC, i.e. just pick all vectors in $\mathbb F_2^k$ except for the all-zero and the all-one vector. This does not work though because there are other ways a SPC subcode can be generated. Indeed, a necessary condition is $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \boldsymbol g_i = 0, \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i = k+1$ where $\boldsymbol g_i$ is the $i$:th column of the generator matrix.

Comment: I think this would be a straightforward job for Gaussian binomial coefficients, if we were satisfied with only linear codes. Alas, we're not!

Comment: I think the notation needs clarification.  What does $\bf{c}_i$ mean?  What does your union mean?  Is it an actual union, or is that meta-notation?  Somehow I think you mean $C_1$ to be a code that adds a single parity check to each of the $k$ data bits. I  have no idea what "and so forth" means.  Also, if $\bf{c}_i$ is a codeword with $n$ bits, its max Hamming weight is $n$, not $2^{k-1}$.  And what exactly do you mean by "subcode." Overall I do not know what you are asking.

Comment: I suspect that your question could be more clearly and concisely formulated in terms of binary sequences, rather than using the language of codes, subcodes, and so on. Of course, I do not know what that question is.

Comment: We're appending *columns* to a codebook matrix in which each row is a codeword, so the columns have length $2^k$ an Hamming weight $2^{k-1}$ if they have an equal amount of zeros and ones. A subcode is a $2^k \times n'$ submatrix of the codebook matrix, where $n'<n$.

Comment: So in this case it seems your union really means "append."  And it seems you are using $C_0$ to denote both a set of codewords (since $\mathbb{F}_2^k$ is the set of all $k$-bit binary strings) as well as a matrix with rows equal to those codewords.  The minimum distance values $d_i$ do not seem relevant to this question.

Comment: A code is nothing more than a set of codewords. This can be represented by a code book matrix. The minimum distance is highly relevant because a single parity check code is equivalent to a (k+1,k,2) code.

Comment: Actually, there was one exploitability in the problem statement which is now edited. In either case, if there is anything else that is ill-posed about this problem, I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with abusing  $\cup$ notation :D

Comment: I may have totally misunderstood something, but... If you don't insist on the code remaining linear, then a few problems come up. 1) You should call the appended codes $[k+1,2^k,d_i]$ codes, because the codes are no longer necessarily vector spaces over $\Bbb{F}_2$. 2) AFAICT a single parity check code of length $k+i$ is a linear code of length $k+i$ and dimension $k+i-1$, so it would need to have $2^{k+i-1}$ codewords. 3) As long as you keep the all zeros word out of the codebook, you will never have a linear subcode - single parity check or otherwise.

Comment: Hmm. What do you mean by a *subcode*? To me it means a subset of the original code. In other words you will throw away some of the $2^k$ *rows* of the codebook, but keep all the $k+i$ columns. The numbers just don't fit. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Great comments, Jyrki. A subcode here means a truncation of symbols, i.e. in the linear case a $k \times n'$ submatrix of the generator. Thus a subcode has the same amount of codewords but less redundancy.

Comment: That's normally called a *punctured code*. The process of discarding a symbol, say the $j$th, from all the words of a code is known as *puncturing*.

Comment: Also, a SPC is indeed always linear (and is the only linear $(k+1,k,2)$ code possible), but a nonlinear code can have the same parameters without being a SPC - but it will be equivalent to a SPC. However, I think the only way to construct such a nonlinear code is by negating the parities, i.e. $x_{k+1} = 1 \oplus \sum_{i=1}^k x_i$

Comment: I would say that any linear $(k+1,k,?)$-code is a single parity check code. A parity check need not involve all the bits. If it doesn't, you get a $(k+1,k,1)$ code.

Comment: I am pretty sure it WILL get you a $(k+1,k,1)$ code unless it involves all the bits. For example, the $(7,4)$ Hamming code can not be punctured to a $(k+1,k,2)$ code.

Comment: Also, semantics. We're defining an SPC as involving all bits.